# When I do git commit, it says nothing added + Macbook Pro created new Github account accidentally?

Tags: git, github

For context, my git use has posed zero problems until I got my new macbook pro and the configuration/settings I've always used were erased. When I tried to set it up for my new computer, it kind of got seriously messed up. I've done some tinkering and the problem is basically that when I add code and try to commit it, it says that nothing has been added. I discovered it's because my "branch" or whatever (I'm not too sure of terminology) is pointing to the directory in github, which obviously didn't change when I added a file to my local directory.

How do I resolve?

FWIW, when I try to commit, I get

```
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.
```

Also, I have my own GitHub account, but I think my computer created its own Github account for me or something? Let's say my name is Joe Smith. If I look at my commit history, it says "Joe Smith authored and Joe Smith committed 1 hour ago." I think one of them is my actual Github, and the other was created by my computer accidentally. This belief is reinforced by the fact that Github says:

**If this commit is yours, make sure joesmith@Joes-MBP.lan is associated with your account.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try and

- make sure my `git config --global user.name` and `git config --global user.email` ar eproperly set (GitHub user account name and email)
- clone the repository again in a new local folder, try and make a local modification, add, commit and push.

See then if you do see your new commit.

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work: "On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean"

Comment: It's because my Git isn't pointing to the local directory I think. I just don't have the knowledge to make it point to the local directory/

Comment: @erfgerwge If you clone the repository, and make modification in it, it will *not* say "nothing to commit, working tree clean": you will add and commit, then push. Only then would it say again "nothing to commit, working tree clean". And you would see your commits published on the remote repository.

Comment: Hi, it didn't work when I added an empty folder to the directory. But it worked when I added a file. Thanks!

Comment: @erfgerwge Great, well done!